# Why is there not stackoverflow.stackexchange.com?

Tags: support, subdomains, domain-names

Ask Ubuntu, for example has `ubuntu.stackexchange.com` redirect. Why does Stack Overflow have no such redirects?

Comment: It is part of the original trio (Super User, Stack Overflow, Server Fault) that predates Stack Exchange as a whole

Comment: Actually asking for that.

Comment: Cause we're speshul

Comment: Because then SO will claim for having stackexchange.stackoverflow.com! (I mean SO, the company is more popular then SE) :p

Comment: They are the same company.

Comment: @ErkinAlpGüney: Why do you need it? Just go to stackoverflow.com like everybody else.

Comment: Regularity and symmetry.

Answer (score 16):

> Why does Stack Overflow have no such redirects?

Because it predates Stack Exchange.

---

By the time the idea of Stack Exchange came up, Stack Overflow was well established - in fact, the original idea was to have a bunch of sites each with their own name, which is why some of the earliest sites in the network have their own names (Stack Overflow, Server Fault, Super User). However that became untenable.

You can ask why we didn't go back then, and change the names of the sites to be `<sitename>.stackexchange.com` - the reason would be that these sites already had an identity, and we didn't want to disrupt that.

Answer (score 14):

Oded described the "why it doesn't exist" part, but to respond to the feature request... we're not going to add a redirect just for the sake of having it. It's a maintenance cost (albeit a minor one) that has little to no practical benefit. At this point in Stack Overflow's history, I don't see why anyone would think to go to `stackoverflow.stackexchange.com` instead of `stackoverflow.com` itself.

Comment: I believe programmers, crawlers, and people with some form of complulsion for order would use (if not demand) the `*.stackexchange.com` pattern. Having the original domains are just more readable and writable.

Comment: @ShooShoSha Dunno about the rest, but programmers and crawlers target stackoverflow.com just fine. :)